# Fixed items and the CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sidebar and header bar that is fixed when scrolling. I also want to lay out my page using CSS grid. I take it that I can't assign the sidebar and header to grid areas, since them having a fixed position conflicts with having a set position in the grid. So, for example, I couldn't write: grid-template-areas: "head head" "side c" "d d". So how would I do it? I read somewhere that I could still put them in the grid if I used 'sticky' but that didn't work. Below is some of my code.

```css
#box-a {
    background: red;
    grid-area: a;
    z-index: 1;
    position: sticky;
    }
    
#box-b {
        width: 200px;
        background: blue;
        grid-area: b;
        position: sticky;
        }    


#box-c {
        grid-area: c;
        background: green;
        }
        
#box-d {
        grid-area: d;
        background: yellow;
}
        
.main {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: "a a"
                           "b c"
                           "d d";
      grid-template-rows: 40px 800px 800px;
      grid-template-columns: 200px 800px;
      }
      
.header-button {
                background: red;
                width: 80px;
                color: white;
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;
                }
                
.header-button:hover {
                      color: yellow;
                      border-bottom: 3px solid black;
                      cursor: pointer;
                     }
             
.side-tile {
            height: 35px;
            border-right: 2px solid black;
            border-left: 2px solid black;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 15px;
            background: blue;
            }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id=box-b>
    <div class=side-tile>
      A
    </div>
    <div class=side-tile>
      B
    </div>
    <div class=side-tile>
      C
    </div>
    <div class=side-tile>
      D
    </div>
    <div class=side-tile>
      E
    </div>
    <div class=side-tile>
      F
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id=box-a>
      <div class=header-button>About</div>
      <div class=header-button>How to</div>
      <div class=header-button>Info</div>
      <div class=header-button>More</div>
   </div>
   <div id=box-c>
   </div>
   <div id=box-d>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why not simply make the green area scrollable ?

Comment: What about when I'm in the yellow area? Or an area underneath the yellow area that I haven't added yet?